# Add image dynamically

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview

I trying to add image into `LinearLayout` (linearForImage) dynamically, but it doesn't work.

```
val image = ImageView(activity)
        image.setLayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams(80, 60))

        for (i in 1..5){
            linearForImage.removeView(image)
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add)
            linearForImage.addView(image)
        }
```

I expect I will get 4 or 5 images in the `LinearLayout`, but there are no image is set.

Comment: why dnt you create a xml file for image view and add it to your Linear layout .?

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi For real scenario, the number of images should not be fixed. I just writing a small example for this.

Comment: Create image instance in for loop and remove that removeView from for loop.

Comment: @Chirag done,but the images still not showing.

Comment: What is the orientation of the Linearlayout?

Comment: @Chirag horizontal

Comment: Show me your xml file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188248/discussion-between-chirag-and-john-joe).

Comment: @JohnJoe like RecycleView you can use a single layout(for different values) to add as many images as  you want by inflating that layout in your linear layout.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code, it is working for me.

```
for (i in 1..5){
   val imageView = ImageView(this)
   imageView.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(80, 60) // value is in pixels
   imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
   linearForImage.addView(imageView)
}
```

Here is the xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearForImage"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: How to increase the image size ?

Comment: LinearLayout.LayoutParams(120, 120)

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the layout , as follows ...

Example : ( In Java )

```
LinearLayout linearForImage = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.imageLayout);
  for(int i=1;i<6;i++)
    {
      ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
      image.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(80,60));
      image.setMaxHeight(20);
      image.setMaxWidth(20);

      // Adds the view to the layout
       linearForImage.addView(image);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set in view of image

```
ivImage.setImageResource(your drawable image)
```

Answer (score 0):

set In Image view
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image)

Comment: There is no imageView object in the question.